# How can I generate permutations from this array?

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array

```
my @arr1 = ("A1", "B1,B2", "C1,C2,C3", ..);
```

how to create new array from this by appending the elements in such a way that it will take one sub-element from @arr1 like A1, B1 & C1 to create a new element "A1B1C1". Sub-elements are separated by ",". The array element number is dynamic.

So the resulting array should look as

```
@out = qw/A1B1C1 A1B1C2 A1B1C3 A1B2C1 A1B2C2 A1B2C3/;
```

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: @Zaid I tried upto spliting elements by "," but gone clueless that what should I do next.

Comment: Please post your code, no matter how broken it is

Comment: Is this another XML question? Because it looks like your previous ones, which were actually about XML. If so, this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: OK. So is this a recursive problem or only 3 keys deep? Because it looks like you're generating permutations.

Comment: @Sobrique This is Excel problem. The elements are Excel cells. & Its a recursive problem. Array length varies as per input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could perform dynamic recursion or reach out to a CPAN module, but I'd use [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) in this case:

```
my @out = glob join '', map "{$_}", @arr1;
```

Comment: ... wow. There's a trick I'd not seen before. Much impressed. (my solution involved some recursive muckery).

Answer (score 4):

For some inscrutable reason I have an aversion to using `glob` to generate cross-products like this. It goes along with my dislike of using `say` in production code, perhaps because it feels like a debugging tool

I can think of nothing wrong with using `glob` in this way, but I thought I should offer a module-based solution in addition to [**Zaid's** fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38697055/622310)

It's easy to assume that either [`Math::Combinatorics`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Combinatorics) or [`Algorithm::Combinatorics`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Combinatorics) will help us here. Together with [`Graph`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Graph), one of these modules is invaluable a component of a Perl programmer's toolbox, but they both work on only a single set of values and it is a cross-product of multiple sets that is required here

I have chosen Brian Foy's [`Set::CrossProduct`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::CrossProduct) here

My benchmarks show that it is around 150 times faster than the `glob` trick, but that shouldn't matter unless the calculation is on the critical path of an application that you are trying to optimise

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Set::CrossProduct;

my @arr1 = ('A1', 'B1,B2', 'C1,C2,C3');

my $iterator = Set::CrossProduct->new( [ map [ split /,/ ], @arr1 ] );

while ( my $tuple = $iterator->get ) {
    say join '', @$tuple;
}
```

#### output

```
A1B1C1
A1B1C2
A1B1C3
A1B2C1
A1B2C2
A1B2C3
```

To use this module in a way plug-compatible with **Zaid's** answer, you would write

```
my @out = map { join '', @$_ } $iterator->combinations;
```

Comment: @ysth: Despite Brian's affectations, I live in a free nation and I may still call him whatever I like. I have honoured him by adding the meaningless `D` and that's as far as I will go. Actually, thinking about it, that has gone too.

Comment: maybe better to not mention his name at all than to mention it in a way that he explicitly says he doesn't feel indicates him?

Comment: @ysth: I'm sure his parents never called him brian d foy, and I have little doubt that they mentioned him. The man is not a god, Just Another Perl Hacker, and pandering to his pretentiousness can only encourage him to think otherwise. He's "the artist formerly known as Brian Foy" and it's exactly the same joke. I wonder what he does for his car registration plates, which cannot contain lower-case letters.